# Rest Assured Body handling ArrayList

Tags: rest-assured

I has a response body like this

```
enter code here

{
"applicationName": "Service MyService",
"someData": [
    {
        "name": "check1",
        "props": [
            "AAaa"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "check2",
        "props": [
            "BBbb",
            "CCcc"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Now I can use the following code and the test passes.

```
        given().log().all()
        .accept(JSON).expect().statusCode(SC_OK)
    .when().log().all()
        .get(contextPath + "/test")
    .then().log().all()
        .body("someData.name",
            IsCollectionWithSize.hasSize(2))
        .body("someData.name",
            allOf(hasItems("check1", "check2")))
        .body("someData.findAll {it.name == 'check1'}.props", 
            IsCollectionWithSize.hasSize(1))
        .body("healthReports.findAll {it.name == 'check2'}.props", 
            IsCollectionWithSize.hasSize(2)));
```

However if I then attempt to check the values in the props field it fails I think because a ArrayList is returned and the matchers are checking on String.

```
        given().log().all()
        .accept(JSON).expect().statusCode(SC_OK)
    .when().log().all()
        .get(contextPath + "/test")
    .then().log().all()
        .body("someData.name",
            IsCollectionWithSize.hasSize(2))
        .body("healthReports.findAll {it.name == 'check1'}.props", 
                    IsCollectionContaining.hasItems(startsWith("AA")));
```

I'm not sure how from the findAll ...props I can check the contents of the ArrayList.

The error displayed is:

```
JSON path someData.findAll {it.name == 'check1'}.props doesn't match.
Expected: (a collection containing a string starting with "AA")
Actual: [[AAaa]]
```

Any idea's ?

Comment: I should have given the error

Answer (score 0):

The findall return an Array of Array containing one element which is AA (which is why you have [[AAaa]] instead of [AAaa].
You have to flatten or extract one level of array to solve the problem I think.